# why processor_t::egalize_privilege(ret_t prv) returns PRV_U if (prv == PRV_HS || (prv == PRV_S && !supports_extension('S')))

Tags: riscv, spike

I cannot understand source code in legalize_privilege() shown below:

```
reg_t processor_t::legalize_privilege(reg_t prv)
{
  if (!supports_extension('U'))
    return PRV_M;

  if (prv == PRV_HS || (prv == PRV_S && !supports_extension('S')))
    return PRV_U;
 //according to my understanding, HS mode actually works in Supervisor mode. So PRV_S should be returned here.
  return prv;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking why PRV_U is returned or why the condition is stated as such?  (Or both..)

Comment: I am sorry for not expressing it clearly.    if possible I hope to know both.

Comment: @Erik Eidt  would you please give me some advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PRV_HS` is only used as a dummy privilege level within the simulator for CSR permission checks.
In the H-extension specification, HS-mode takes the place of S-mode (level `1`).
The integer value `2` is used for `PRV_HS` to distinguish it from `PRV_S`, but that is a reserved value in the RISC-V Privileged Architecture ([ISA Manual Vol. 2](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/releases/download/Ratified-IMFDQC-and-Priv-v1.11/riscv-privileged-20190608.pdf) § 1.2 Privilege Levels) and not used by the H-extension.

It is therefore illegal to actually set this mode. To set either HS- or S-mode, always use `PRV_S`.
In the same condition, you can also see that it is illegal to set S-mode if the S-extension is not supported.
Both of these cases are illegal, so the privilege level is instead forced to the lowest level, which is `PRV_U`.

---

The only use of `PRV_HS` is in the permission check segment of `processor_t::get_csr` ([here](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim/blob/master/riscv/processor.cc#L1768)), where it is used instead of `PRV_S` if the processor is not in a virtual state (as set by `processor_t::set_virt`), to permit access to Hypervisor CSRs.
This is because the CSR address encodes the minimum privilege level required for access in bits [9:8], which is defined as `10b = 2` for Hypervisor CSRs, even though there is no such distinct privilege level ([ISA Manual Vol. 2](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/releases/download/Ratified-IMFDQC-and-Priv-v1.11/riscv-privileged-20190608.pdf) § 2.1 CSR Address Mapping Conventions).